# Push notification in next updated version

Tags: iphone, ios, apple-push-notifications

I have an app version 1.0 which is on Appstore, now I want to update this app and also want to integrate push notifications to this app. Now my question is since the provision profile, that signed with last version ,has not been configured for push notifications, now If I configure the push notification ,will push notifications will be available on updating the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to recreate the profile, redownload it and resign the new version with this in.

You can verify it is enabled by creating an ADHOC profile and doing some live testing (which you should be doing anyway!)

Comment: Will it effect the existing users of my app, also after resigning with     new profile will it show an update to an existing user.

Comment: No it won't affect them.  You still need to add the code in the AppDelegate to turn on the push notifications and retrieve the device token and users will see a message requesting access.

Comment: Today I got my app version1.1 updated on appstore and sadly I did not recieved push notifications, actually it not even asking for push notification services.

Comment: could you explain the process for me